# use variadic template to implement general purpose unrestricted union

Tags: c++, c++11

[Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions) contains example for an unrestricted union, which has an union containing non-POD types and an enum indicating which member of union is active.

I want to generalize this idea, which is

```
template <typename... T>
class Union {
  int active_member_;
  union {
    T...
  };
};
```

However, I can't figure out the details.  Anyone has an idea how I can actually access the ith-member in union given the integer i?

Comment: You can’t (not at runtime, that is). The code is not supposed to be able to do this.

Comment: You may look at [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html)